# How to export all tables data into csv or excel format in MySQL using a script or some other way ?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, export-to-csv

I have the following problem. I have a production table on a server its like `12GB` and what i wanted is to just pull off the data form production and import it into my local database for ease operation.

AT the end i want to submit the data in `CSV` or `Excel` format to the client. But , i need to have automated script which can import each tables data into a csv file , as naming it by the table name or something ? can you really help on this , i appreciated it?

Answer (score 4):

Check out `mysqldump` with `--tab` option. It outputs one file per tale, naming the files according to the table names, and the contents of the file is tab-delimited text.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tab

You can then import the text files into Excel, and you can [change the delimiter between fields to tab](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-HP010099725.aspx#BMchange_the_delimiter_that_is_used_in_).

You may also want to import the data directly into Excel without needing to use an intermediate text file. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-import.html

Comment: hey! it not what i want clients does have to do anything except seening the data they already have?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method I did after some research is to run a python script.
Put all the required tables in a list and loop over the list.
The following python script will export all the tables into corresponding csv files

```
import MySQLdb
import csv

user = '' # your username
passwd = '' # your password
host = '' # your host or localhost if running locally
db = '' # database where your table is stored
dest_folder = '' # destination folder for the files to be written

table_list = []    
for table in table_list:
    print(table)
    con = MySQLdb.connect(user=user, passwd=passwd, host=host, db=db)
    cursor = con.cursor()

    query = "SELECT * FROM %s;" % table
    cursor.execute(query)

    with open(folder + table + '.csv','w') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            writer.writerow(row)
```

If you get an error saying that `no module named MySQLdb`, then install `MySQLdb` using the following methods

```
1. easy_install mysql-python
2. pip install mysql-python
3. pip install mysqlclient 
4. apt-get install python-mysqldb (Ubuntu - my preferred OS)
```

Comment: it currently exports them, but without column names

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic python script that does the work! You can also choose to export only the headers (column names) or headers & data both.

Just change the database credentials and run the script. It will output all the data to the output folder.

To run the script -

1. Run: pip install mysql-connector-python
2. Change database credentials in the "INPUT" section
3. Run: python filename.py

```
import mysql.connector
from pathlib import Path
import csv 

#========INPUT===========
databaseHost=""
databaseUsername=""
databasePassword=""
databaseName=""
outputDirectory="./WITH-DATA/"
exportTableData=True #MAKING THIS FIELD FALSE WILL STORE ONLY THE TABLE HEADERS (COLUMN NAMES) IN THE CSV FILE
#========INPUT END===========


Path(outputDirectory).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host=databaseHost,
  user=databaseUsername,
  password=databasePassword
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("USE "+databaseName)


mycursor.execute("SHOW TABLES")
tables = mycursor.fetchall()  

tableNames=[table[0] for table in tables]

print("================================")
print("Total number of tables: "+ str(len(tableNames)))
print(tableNames)
print("================================")

for tableName in tableNames:

    print("================================")
    print("Processing: "+ str(tableName))

    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host=databaseHost,
        user=databaseUsername,
        password=databasePassword
    )
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("USE "+databaseName)

    if exportTableData:
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM "+tableName)
    else:
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM "+tableName+" LIMIT 1")

    print(mycursor.column_names)

    with open(outputDirectory+tableName+".csv", 'w', newline='') as csvfile: 
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) 

        csvwriter.writerow(mycursor.column_names) 

        if exportTableData:
            myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
            csvwriter.writerows(myresult)
```

[image: Output folders]

[image: CSV file for each table]

[image: Data inside the CSV]